# Monte Carlo simulation for Geometric Brownian motion in R giving negative numbers

Tags: r, montecarlo, stochastic-process

I was under the impression that simulations involving geometric brownian motion are not supposed to yield negative numbers. However, I was trying the following Monte Carlo simulation in R for a GBM, where my initial asset price is: $98.78$, $\mu = 0.208$, $\sigma = 0.824$. I initialized my dataframe as such: (I am just doing 1000 simulations over 5 years, simulating the price each year)

```
V = matrix(0, nrow = 1000, ncol = 6)
V_df = data.frame(V)
```

Then:

```
V[, 1] <- 98.78
```

I then perform the simulations (with dt = 1):

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
        for (j in 1:5) {
            V_df[i,j+1] <- V_df[i,j]*(mu*dt + sigma*sqrt(dt)*rnorm(1)) + V_df[i,j]
        }
    }
```

When I then check V_df there are many negative entries, which is not supposed to be the case. Would anyone have an idea as to why this is so?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your solution to the GBM is not correct. One step should read

```
V_df[i,j+1] <- V_df[i,j]*exp((mu - sigma^2/2)*dt + sigma*sqrt(dt)*rnorm(1))
```

However, doing this with a double loop is **very inefficient**. You can create a matrix of random numbers and use `cumprod` or `cumsum` to generate the paths. Which function you use depends on when you take the `exp`.

See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion